# How to fetch data from firebase realtime database to my table in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, fetch

I'm new to firebase and I'm trying to fetch my data from the firebase realtime-database into my table. And I can't seem to do it. I'm stuck at this for almost 2-3 days, I watch most of the tutorials on youtube and can't really get a hang of it. Can you please help me?

ps: I've put a link of my firebase realtime-database below and the code for my table and javascript and another picture for the HTML table page. [My Realtime Database Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcetz.png) [my HTML table page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWa9C.png)

```js
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyC4zncL7q8dd69Pw2TdZNB_My8RxbcPk-c",
  authDomain: "sample-78da2.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://sample-78da2-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "sample-78da2",
  storageBucket: "sample-78da2.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "772404929249",
  appId: "1:772404929249:web:b7ab0f6790f7fe7ce10da0",
  measurementId: "G-076CP33W46"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
firebase.analytics();

//Get a reference to the database service
var database = firebase.database();

function SelectAllData() {
  firebase.database().ref('Users').once('value',
    function(AllRecords) {
      AllRecords.forEach(
        function(CurrentRecord) {
          var last = CurrentRecord.val().lastName;
          var first = CurrentRecord.val().firstName;
          var middle = CurrentRecord.val().middleName;
          var email = CurrentRecord.val().email;
          var gender = CurrentRecord.val().gender;
          AddItemsToTable(last, first, middle, email, gender, );

        }
      );
    });
}

window.onload = SelectAllData;

var pInf = 0;

function AddItemsToTable(last, first, middle, email, gender, ) {
  var tbody = document.getElementById('tbody1');
  var trow = document.createElement('tr');
  var td1 = document.createElement('td');
  var td2 = document.createElement('td');
  var td3 = document.createElement('td');
  var td4 = document.createElement('td');
  var td5 = document.createElement('td');
  var td6 = document.createElement('td');

  td1.innerHTML = ++pInf;
  td2.innerHTML = last;
  td3.innerHTML = first;
  td4.innerHTML = middle;
  td5.innerHTML = email;
  td6.innerHTML = gender;

  trow.appendChild(td1);
  trow.appendChild(td2);
  trow.appendChild(td3);
  trow.appendChild(td4);
  trow.appendChild(td5);
  trow.appendChild(td6);
  tbody.appendChild(trow);

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <title>MR. CHECKY | Tables</title>
  <link href="checky/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="checky/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="checky/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="adminDashboard.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.6.2/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
  <script src="sample.js"></script>
  <script src="signOut.js"></script>

</head>

<body id="page-top">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-dark bg-dark static-top">

    <a class="navbar-brand mr-1" href="adminDashboard.html">MR. CHECKY</a>

    <button class="btn btn-link btn-sm text-white order-1 order-sm-0" id="sidebarToggle" href="#">
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
      </button>

    <!-- Navbar Search -->
    <form class="d-none d-md-inline-block form-inline ml-auto mr-0 mr-md-3 my-2 my-md-0">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">
              <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
            </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </nav>

  <div id="wrapper">

    <!-- Sidebar -->
    <ul class="sidebar navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="adminDashboard.html">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-tachometer-alt"></i>
          <span>Dashboard</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="adminAnnouncement.html">
          <i class="fas fa-bullhorn"></i>
          <span>Announcement</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="pagesDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></i>
          <span>Pages</span>
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="pagesDropdown">
          <h6 class="dropdown-header">Login Screens:</h6>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="adminRegister.html">Register</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="adminForgotPassword.html">Forgot Password</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="charts.html">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-chart-area"></i>
          <span>Charts</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="tables.html">
          <i class="fas fa-fw fa-table"></i>
          <span>Users Tables</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item" id="out" onclick="signOut()">
        <a class="nav-link">
          <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt" id="icon"></i>
          <span class="btnOut">Log-out</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div id="content-wrapper">

      <div class="container-fluid">

        <!-- Breadcrumbs-->
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item">
            <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
          </li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Tables</li>
        </ol>

        <!-- DataTables Example -->
        <div class="card mb-3">
          <div class="card-header">
            <i class="fas fa-table"></i> Users Table | MR. CHECKY</div>
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead class="header">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Middle Initial</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Contact Number</th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot class="header">
                  <tr>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Middle Initial</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                    <th>Contact Number</th>
                  </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody id="tbody1">
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="card-footer small text-muted">Updated yesterday at 11:59 PM</div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <!-- Sticky Footer -->
      <footer class="sticky-footer">
        <div class="container my-auto">
          <div class="copyright text-center my-auto">
            <span>Copyright © MR. CHECKY 2021</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </footer>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Scroll to Top Button-->
  <a class="scroll-to-top rounded" href="#page-top">
    <i class="fas fa-angle-up"></i>
  </a>

  <script src="checky/jquery/jquery2.js"></script>
  <script src="checky/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="checky/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
  <script src="checky/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <script src="checky/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap4.js"></script>
  <script src="sb-admin.min.js"></script>
  <script src="tables-chart/datatables-demo.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: are you getting any errors?


 firebase.database()ref


should be:
firebase.database().ref

Comment: I'm not having any errors except for what u said. I already fixed it, but I still cant get my data from firebase to my web app

Comment: where is your reference to the database?

  // Get a reference to the database service
  var database = firebase.database();


https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start

Comment: @bowl_of_rice I've changed my javascript to this one. All I'm getting is the "No data available in table" in the table.  (my firebase database is still the same) I've also put my entire HTML page for the table.